# Is it possible to use 2 relays instead of a DC motor controller?

Tags: motor, relay, dc-motor, robotics, motor-controller

I have been for motor controllers to control two 12V motors that have a stall current of 130A and at max power (expected operation) will draw 68A.

I am having trouble finding low cost motor controllers for these motors.  I do not need to be able to control speed but only need on/off in both directions.

Can 2 relays per motor be used instead?

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Absolutely, provided you don't need coasting. Connect the common terminals of 2 SPDT relays to each motor connection, and each of the throws to V+ and V-, connecting each to the same throw on each relay. Activating either single coil will cause the motor to turn in each direction, and activating neither or both coils will cause it to brake.

Comment: Just remember to add a couple of diodes or the relays contacts will wear out in the blink of an eye.

Comment: I was going to wire it like this:

http://www.bpesolutions.com/gadgets.ws/gprojects/svrelay1.gif

Where should I put the diodes and what specs should I be aware of when purchasing diodes?